# Не могу получить Ip4

Tags: c#

Использую

```
public static IPAddress GetIP4Address() {
    return Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()).FirstOrDefault(IPA => IPA.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
}
```

Но получаю ошибку

Argumentnullexception: argument cannot be null
Parametr name : hostNameorAddress

Comment: Приведенный код не имеет абсолютно никакого смысла. Опишите решаемую задачу.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight я хотел узнать как ее решить -  вызываю код через Console.Write(GetIP4Address()); b получаю Argumentnullexception

Comment: Это я понял. Непонятно, что должен делать этот код. Если нужно получить локальный IP, это делается по другому. См. например здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/830696/240512