# Как определить IP-адрес любого компьютера во внутренней сети, зная список IP-адресов данного узла?

Tags: c#, winforms, сеть, ip, ip-address

Допустим, есть компьютер в локальной сети, который принимает ip-адрес от DHCP сервера ИЛИ использует ip-адрес, который задается вручную самим пользователем. Мне нужно определить ip-адрес внутренней сети любой машины, на котором я буду запускать свою программу.

У меня есть код, который получает диапазон IP-адресов при помощи маски подсети типа C (27, CIDR) и выводит все это в `TextBox`.

```
#region Вычисление начального и конечного ip-адреса
String host = Dns.GetHostName(); // Имя моего хоста - Server
IPAddress ip = Dns.GetHostEntry(host).AddressList[1]; // ip-адрес мой - 10.0.21.182(/27)
UInt32 a = Convert.ToUInt32(ip.Address); // перевожу свой ip в 32-битное число без знака
UInt32 b = 0xe0ffffff; // создаю маску подсети с CIDR-кодом 27 (HEX)
UInt32 c = a & b; // накладываю маску подсети на ip и получаю сетевой адрес
byte[] с1 = BitConverter.GetBytes(c); // 10.0.21.160
с1[3]++; // получаем начальный диапазон 10.0.21.161 - начальный адрес сети резервируется для идентификации подсети
UInt32 b2 = ~b; // создаю обратную маску подсети через побитовое отрицание - 0.0.0.31
c = a | b2; // получаю конечный сетевой адрес диапазон
byte[] с2 = BitConverter.GetBytes(c); // широковещательный адрес 10.0.21.191
с2[3]--; // получаем конечный сетевой адрес диапазон 10.0.21.191
#endregion

#region Вывод диапазона ip-адресов
searchIPPanelPanelTool_RangeIP.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
   if (i != 3)
      searchIPPanelPanelTool_RangeIP.Text += с1[i].ToString() + ".";
   else searchIPPanelPanelTool_RangeIP.Text += с1[i].ToString();
searchIPPanelPanelTool_RangeIP.Text += "-";
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
   if (i != 3)
      searchIPPanelPanelTool_RangeIP.Text += с2[i].ToString() + ".";
   else searchIPPanelPanelTool_RangeIP.Text += с2[i].ToString();
#endregion
```

**P.S.:**
*IP-адрес у меня не составляет труда получить, но только в качестве списка всех интерфейсов подключения. В этом то списке и сидит мой локальный адрес. 
Но дело в том, что порядок списка на других компах может быть совершенно другой и класс:*

```
IPAddress ip_host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList[1];
```

*с элементом списка 1 уже не работает - я просто получу ip-адрес другого интерфейса.*

**Как это сделать таким образом, чтобы я мог определять IP-адрес внутренней (локальной) сети любого компьютера?**

Comment: вы хотите узнать свой IP не вбивая четко `1` в `AddressList`? я верно понял?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц , Да )) Иначе, из-за этого статического индекса, я не могу сделать нормальное определение диапазона IP-адресов машины. На разных компах работает по разному...

Comment: По идее правильно так. Перечислить все сетевые интерфейсы локальной машины, откинуть те, которые относятся к виртуальным машинам (например, содержат в имени VmWare). Прочитать параметры интерфейса IpV4 и IpV6, убедиться что шлюз по умолчанию пустой (т.е. машина не имеет выхода в интернет - сетка "внутренняя"). Таких интерфейсов может быть более одного (у меня на виртуалке есть такой хост), вы не можете считать, что таких интерфейсов строго один будет (и как вы будете разруливать такую ситуацию - я не знаю).

Comment: @AK, каким образом разруливать - костылями, а чем же еще ? ))  Мне просто до жути интересно, как работают другие программы для администрирования сети, в которых я открываю форму поисках ip-адресов машин локальной сети и вижу сразу готовый свой диапазон ip-адресов своей машины. Причем! Эта программа работает на всех ПК...

Comment: Поставьте эту вашу программу на виртуалку с двумя локальными интерфейсами и посмотрите, будет ли работать или сразу заткнётся.

Comment: @AK, хорошая идея - потом попробую. Думаю тоже, сдохнет ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как вариант (затратный) и требует инет:

```
        string localIP;
        using (Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, 0))
        {
            socket.Connect("8.8.8.8", 65530);
            IPEndPoint endPoint = socket.LocalEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
            localIP = endPoint.Address.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(localIP);
        }
```

вариант 2

```
        var host = Dns.GetHostName();
        foreach (var ip in Dns.GetHostEntry(host).AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork) Console.WriteLine(ip.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Ух ты, про сокеты я вообще забыл!  Работать то будет без проблем (не сильно затратный), но опять же, как вы и сказали - ИНТЕРНЕТ нужен...

Comment: @Алексей подсунал 2 вариант

Comment: Допустим. Я тоже так думал, но тут действует тогда одно НО - а что, если у меня несколько интерфейсов, несколько сетевых устройств? Допустим, я смогу отсеять IPv6, но тогда что делать, если у меня 2 ip-адреса хранятся в этом списке? А на других машинах вообще может быть их 3, 5 и т.д.

Comment: @Алексей смотря что вы хотите дальше с этим адресом делать...вы ж все равно будите отсеевать как то...вот какие у вас будут условия, если их будет несколько?

Comment: Я пишу клиент-серверную прогу, для диплома. Мне нужно сделать прогу, которая администрирует локальную сеть.

Comment: @Алексей а IP зачем узнавать программным путем? это хреново с точки зрения безопасности. И как у вас клиент с сервером общается?

Comment: IP мне нужен для того, чтобы понять в какой сети сидит комп, который юзает моя прога. Далее, по этому IP я вычисляю диапазон адресов (например, 10.0.21.161-10.0.21.190), в пределах которого я пытаюсь соединится с хостом по определенному порту открытому и если соединение устанавливается, то хост в сети считается для меня открытым. Просто, предполагается, что у меня на каждом хосте будет стоять мини-сервак, который будет держать открытым определенный порт для соединения с моей прогой.

Comment: Хороший пример тому, программа RMS.

Comment: @Алексей ну тогда вариант с сокетами для вас 100%...просто ip и порт гугла менять на ip и открытыый порт любого из ваших сервов..и ip у вас в руках

Comment: @Алексей как вариант сделать прослойку между серваком и клиентом...которая будит выступать за "всезнающего гения"...на нем развернуть сокет, к которому будут конектиться и серваки и клиенты все. и потом вам останется у него только спросить "а кто к тебе подключен?"

Comment: А в качестве безопасности, можно сделать, чтобы при соединении по порту с этим хостом, спрашивался пароль - 3 не правильных ввода и этот IP-адрес блокируется. Так можно будет не переживать за атаку ))

Comment: @Алексей сейчас в моде токены...а пароль при коннекте это глупо..а вот в качесте 2 ряда защиты он подойдет

Comment: Так, что за "прослойка" такая между сервак и хостом? С токенами вообще никогда дела не имел, это сложно? Про пароли согласен, в качестве дополнительной меры - да, но не основной. 

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93759/discussion-between---and-).

Comment: Давайте, я там ))

Answer (score 1):

Никак. У компьютера нет никакого "IP-адреса во внутренней сети", IP-адрес - это свойство интерфейса, а не компьютера. Компьютер может иметь любое число интерфейсов, в том числе, смотрящих в одну сеть (хотя такая конфигурация на практике бессмысленна) или смотрящих в разные сети, каждая из которых имеет маршрут до вашего сервера. Строка `Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName())` никак не решает эту задачу. По сути, она просто возвращает IP-адрес текущего компьютера, как его видит DNS-сервер. Это, с высокой вероятностью, **не** то, что вам нужно (зачем вообще приплетать DNS?)

Для частного случая, когда компьютер имеет только один физический интерфейс, можно воспользоваться решением отсюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/830696/240512 и взять первый IP-адрес из коллекции, возвращенной методом `GetIpAddresses()`.

Comment: А как насчет того, что просто использовать ARP таблицу и вытаскивать оттуда ip-диапазон? По поводу DNS согласен, но это единственный способ, который я знал и юзал...

Comment: @Алексей В ARP таблице также будут все адреса при наличии нескольких интерфейсов

Comment: Даже если я и воспользуюсь вашим методом, все равно есть вероятность, что первый адрес будет не того интерфейса, которого мне надо. Но, спасибо!

Comment: @Алексей а вы можете дать больше информации о ваших критериях "надо" и "не надо"? "Не надо" те, у которых нет маршрута до вашего сервера?